# google analytics catch on page load

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics

I wanna catch GA on Page load

and I try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ga('send', 'event', 'Page', 'Viewing', 'A_Page');
});
```

It's not working..

Is it impossible catch page load in GA?

---

Solution....

```
function main_view_ga() {
  ga( "send", "event", "Page", "View", "A_Page");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function () {main_view_ga()}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You are most likely using asynchronous version. In which case document.ready does not mean that GA script is loaded. Wrap your code inside a `setTimeout`.

Comment: @SalmanA It working good!! XD

Comment: @SalmanA my mistake... modify asap

Answer (score 1):

"document.ready" is not "page load". It's when the DOM is set up completely. So, proper solution: If you want to track page load simply place your tracking code directly after the google code in the page head (your event tracking code does seem to do the same as a standard pageview call in any case).

The timeout is a hack - it does not really test if the analytics library is loaded, it simply hopes that  it will be there eventually when you wait long enough. Plus of course it means you are even further removed from the page load (you are triggering a tag one second after DOM completion, which is a rather different thing).

If you really want to track DOM completion (which GA does by itself, you can get information in the behavior->page speed section) you might as well load the analytics library inside the document.ready tag.

Of course users might choose to abandon your page before the DOM is ready, so this will probably give you different numbers than a tracking code simply put in the head.

Comment: Load GA library inside document.ready is not working :( if   youknow load and working completely code, comment Please. :)

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout method worked perfectly for me, because I am am on a large scale corporate web site, where we need to add this to specific activities on the page (not just the page loading) such as an AB control test...

One experience will have a page load impression for the control with a specific ga function, the other will load the impression for the control with a different function (one containing the word control the other with the word test).

Thank you for this! we were about to ditch the javascript method and go with the old method of analytics activity id tags..